# Can't find a way to parse my json in c

Tags: c, json, parsing

Yo ! I'm coding in c on code::block (windows) and i can't find an easy way or a good library to parse my json, what should I use ? Thanks

Comment: "An easy way" is *highly* subjective. Anyway, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Yo.

Comment: [jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.json.org
Maintains a list of libraries for many languages. Check some of them out

Comment: I checked this but none of c libraries describe a way to install it in code::blocks.

Comment: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_(general)#Q:_I_would_like_to_compile_a_project_using_some_non-standard_libraries._How_can_I_indicate_to_CodeBlocks_that_these_libraries_and_include_files_exist.3F may help

Comment: Already checked this link, it seems that it won't work with librairies i tried.

Comment: Seems you need to learn to use the ide better. As that is the correct way